# Shell script execution on multiple servers

Tags: linux, ssh, scripting

Is it possible to run one part of the ksh/sh script on one server then ssh to another server and continue with the rest of the script? Or is there a work-around?

I have a user with which I don't have to authenticate each time I access a server, so I can hop from one server to another without any keyboard interaction.

I've already tried this, trying to separate some logic into another script then :

```
MYSCRIPT="nohup ksh myscript.ksh > mylog.log &"
ssh servername ${MYSCRIPT}
```

I tried this but it doesn't seem to execute this script on another server.

The whole code above is part of a `for` loop; I execute the same script for a list of servers.

For testing purposes, the list has two servers; for some weird and twisted reason, only the last (or second) server script works as I expect.

All servers can see myscript.ksh -- it is visible and executable to all of them.

Comment: Perhaps post a bit more code. My test example which looks just like your code seems to work fine.

Comment: Where is myscript.ksh?  Unless it's in your home directory, you should be running `myscript.ksh`, not `ksh myscript.ksh`.

Comment: If your routing/fw allows it, I'd rather suggest that you coordinate your remote server access from one central host without hopping around (at least, that's how I fetch my backups).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to run a sequence of commands on another server without having to log in multiple times. To accomplish this, you could do:

```
local_command sequence
ssh remote-server << End-Of-File
        remote_command 1
        remote_command 2
        remote_command 3
End-Of-File
```

This would run `remote_command 1`, and when it finishes, run `remote_command 2`, then `remote_command 3` all on the remote server

Comment: I like this approach, can you please give an example, or a man page, I think this is what I want.. I want to execute entire script many lines on multiple servers

Comment: Gotcha

Answer (score 1):

To be honest your wording is a bit vague but let's trace possible causes:

What you described should work just fine, but see `ssh-copy-id` source to look for discrepancies with your own script (it is a shell script bundled with OpenSSH).

You mentioned that the command does not work on one of your machines, maybe the server has a different setup preventing the script to start in the first place.

Also, you mentioned authentication, so I suppose you're using passwordless public key authentication, and you might want to restrict the commands authorized with the associated key: see `man ssh`, section `AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT`.